# Difference monitor resources 4k UHD vs QHD

Tags: display, 4k-resolution

I would like to know if connecting a 4k UHD monitor instead of a QHD affects the speed of my notebook.
In practice it takes more resources to view images? slows down the pc?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UHD is typically 3840x2160 pixels. QHD is usually 2560x1440.
Please note I say typically and usually because plenty of vendors play fast and loose with terminology to make their product look better in the marketing material.
Neither is actually truly 4K: That would be 4096x2160.

So a UHD screen has more pixels than a QHD screen. Which mean your video-card needs to push more data to the screen and use more video-RAM for display buffers.
So UHD takes a bit more resources which, if your computers is under-powered (like many laptops with CPU-based graphics instead of a dedicated video-card) to begin with, might be noticeable.
For normal Windows work it is probably hardly noticeable. But in games it will show, if you run the game at the maximum supported resolution. You can off-course always go back to a lower resolution to improve performance.

Comment: I have a Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz with 16GB of ram and I don't use for gaming but only for programming... I think I shouldn't have any problems. Thanks

Comment: @user2005016 In that case you probably won't notice at all. I'm typing this on a similar spec laptop with 2 UHD screens attached (on the thunderbolt dock) and with the Full-HD internal LCD in operation as well. I don't see any noticeable slowdown compared to just using the internal LCD.